# How to center an image in the nav-bar when it shrinks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a template to build website (https://github.com/learning-zone/website-templates/tree/master/victory-educational-institution-free-html5-bootstrap-template) and the original nav-bar looks like this:

Before shrinking:
[nav-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSkZK.png)

After shrinking::
[nav-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH2Le.png)

I changed the logo to mine. Because mine is vertically smaller, so I changed the margin from 10px to 20px

```
.logo {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0;
}
```

It looks like centered:
[nav-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vJvg.png)

But when I scroll down the page, the navigation bar shrinks, and my logo doesn't stay vertically center. It goes up.
[nav-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwRdk.png)

I tried to fix the css, but it doesn't work

```
.logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0;
}
```

This is the html for that logo

```
<div class="logo smooth-scroll">
    <a href="#banner"><img id="logo" src="images/boxinghub.png" alt="boxinghub logo"></a>
</div>
```

The code in css control the position when shrinking, but even I add .logo or #logo, it doesn't help.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .fixed-header-on .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Thx in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use background methods like `background-position: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after add these lines of code:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    #logo {
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

But I still don't know how and why `@media` controls shrinking...Does anybody know?